# How to find absolute position of an element where there is no offsetParent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am developing a firefox extension. So I am dealing with many websites.

I have to get absolute position of my element.There are some pages in which there is no offsetParent at all for my given element?

So in this scenario `offset()` method of jquery returns `[0,0]` and `offsetParent()` returns an object of length zero.

How can I handle this?

Comment: HTML code examples? Have you already tried [`element.getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect)?

Comment: I don't have any code examples. I can show you the website with which I am facing problem. http://www.amazon.com/Breaking-Windows-Fumbled-Future-Microsoft/dp/0743203151 . I am trying to find the absolute position of the links under "Customers Who Bought This Item Also Bought" section.

Yes I tried getBoundingClientRect too.

Comment: Which browser(s)? I have looped through each element in that set of links, and there wasn't any `offset()` method which returned `top=0 and left=0`.

Comment: Firefox 5.0.1. Did you tried in FF?

Comment: Tried @FF 3.6.23. Can you copy the relevant part of the document to a fiddle, so I can verify it?

Comment: Ok. I will copy it for you. I observe another thing. These links are inside `<li>`. Is there anything to do with this. Generally I am having problems with links inside a table or frame.

Comment: '`offsetParent` returns null when the element has `style.display` set to "none".' - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetParent